# outlook multiple email sends

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm running Office 365 Outlook and I have this annoying issue where certain emails I send end up stuck in my Outbox and multiple copies get sent out to external recipients before I notice.  I forwarded one of the same messages to myself and I also receive multiple copies.

It seems to happen with larger attachments and I found an MS support page that suggested I set Outlook to work offline and then remove the attachment and/or the outbound message.

That's a fine after the fact procedure but what I'd like to do is prevent the problems and avoid the nuisance for others.  I see that I can change the registry to change the default 20 MB limit but that doesn't help prevent the problem.

Not sure if it's relevant but I noticed that some of my more recent received emails ended up getting duplicated when I first connected my Outlook to my gmail account.

I appreciate any insight into this annoying problem and would prefer to determine the root cause and correct rather than throw in the towel and go to the gmail web portal or thunderbird.

Comment: Is your internet connection stable?  What is the speed?  How did you setup your connection to Gmail?

Comment: Yeah, internet is stable with 50/10 mbit ADSL and I used an IMAP connector

Comment: 10Mb up is slow and the ADSL speed is  usually 'potential' not actual.  Distance from Telco,  quality of phone lines and connections will eat into that.  Also, you and your neighbors may be sharing bandwidth.  Synchronizing multiple Gmail folders, and saturating your up pipe for extended periods of time are likely causing interruptions (dropped packets).  Email is designed to err on the side of caution. if it can't confirm that the send was acknowledged it will try again.  I reccomend you use Gmail web client which has negligible  load. Thunderbird won't solve this.

Comment: You can run a speed test while performing a send receive with a big outgoing message, and also with Outlook closed to confirm the actual bandwidth to your PC. Also sonething that tests packet loss would be good.  Many types of internet traffic are resilliant to interruptions but anything secure will need to reauthenticate every time there is an interruption.

Comment: The problematic system is running in a VM so I think it must be environmental as my work laptop running corporate Office 365 hasn't ever had this issue.   I just sent a 16 MB attachment from work -> personal email and it went out very quickly over the same internet connection.   Outlook within the VM took a very long time to pull it down right after but the send/receive phase is always sluggish in this VM.   I think I'll see if I can find the sync logs to get a sense of where it's struggling

Comment: I spoke too soon there, the 16 MB pdf is marked as sent but hasn't come through so it may be stuck in some gmail scanning phase.   I'll monitor that, look into the outlook logs and report back

Comment: So the test file sent from my work hit a send limit which exlained why it never arrive and a tweak to the IMAP send settings to sped up the checking 'subscribed' folders a lot.   I decided to then test things on Thunderbird and while it was slow to send them out, it successfully sent out just one copy of a 5, 10 and 15 MB powershell generated test file.  (1 of 2)

Comment: I then opened Outlook and forwarded the 5 MB file to myself. That ended up with two copies in Sent and Inbox before it left the outbox. Tried the same with the 10 MB file and it remained stuck in the outbox with ever increasing copies in sent and inbox. Then it was back to Thunderbird where a forward of the same 10 MB worked as expected. One copy in sent and another in Inbox. Given that Thunderbird works immediately before and after Outlook acting up, it seems the problem is with Outlook. (2 of 2)

Comment: The way I stopped the 10 MB one in Outlook was to set it offline.   Strangely when back online later it managed to finally send it one more time and realize it had done so.

Comment: Incidentally, Thunderbird never put the file in an Outbox but rather threw up a dialog with a progress bar upon send.  Thinking that this less asyncronous approach (not having an Outbox with likely some background threads to process( to transmission is what makes Thunderbird a more reliable transmission agent.

Comment: I think I'll file a support ticket with MS pointing to this post and see if they have any ideas.  It's kind of embarassing when you send your accountant a 10 MB zip of tax files at the end of the day from your Outlook thick client and they wake up with a whole ton of copies!

Comment: One last test of a 10 MB file from my work Outlook client to my personal email also worked and was SUPER fast.   Definitely something to do with some combination of my VM, gmail IMAP or and Outlook 365.   Getting Thunderbird to send out as fast as my work email prior to trying Outlook again will hopefully allow Outlook's lack of reliabille transmission to be a non factor.

Comment: What about enabling the "Don't save copies of sent items" via Account Settings > Account Settings?

Comment: I actually do want to keep copies of sent items as that can come in very handy sometimes. I noticed today that Outlook is now also resulting in double sending of super short text only messages. I can't believe how that is happening in a core MS product that's been around so long. There surely must be some way to build in some realiability checking into the tranmission phase! Seems some hooks are available at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMTP_server_return_codes.  Presumably some could be used to firm up the SMTP send ACK's but who knows?  Time to abandon Outlook for now and use Thunderbird